# Unauthenticated user in mysql processes list - hack attempt?

Tags: mysql, security

I see frequently when I run `mysqladmin proc` or when I review the MySQL Server process list a user marked with: unauthenticated user trying to connect.

```
+-----+----------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+------+------------------+------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| Id  | User                 | Host         | db              | Command | Time | State            | Info             | Rows_sent | Rows_examined | Rows_read |
+-----+----------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+------+------------------+------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| 40  | unauthenticated user | x.x.x.x:xxxx |                 | Connect |      | Reading from net |                  | 0         | 0             | 0         |
```

What may causes such thing?

Is that normal, or should I investigate my system for any vulnerability or security breach?

Thanks

Comment: Is x.x.x.x your machine? Generally you don't want MySQL listening on the public Internet.

Comment: Yes, x.x.x.x is the local network IP Range of my cluster. You are right, It's not listening to public already. My worries are about someone trying to brute force the MySQL server to get access via some vulnerable bug or so in my own application. This is why I asked this :).
Thanks for your reminder.. @bobince

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unauthenticated user` is the user connected and not yet sent authentication credentials. Doesn't look like a hack attempt to me.